# Dropdown list to select model on category page

Tags: magento-1.9, dropdown-attribute

I Am Working on a cell phones battery project, so there are so many categories like `micromax`, `intex` etc.

I want a `drop down menu` on category page where visitors can select there phone model and then website will show result as per model, can anybody guide me how can I do that?

There are 500 products.

Comment: try this extension http://www.magedelight.com/parts-finder.html. It helps you to find the related products with multiple attributes

Comment: thank u, this the thing i want..but its costly, please show any free extension or give any other idea pleaseee

Answer (score 2):

Make your categories as layered navigation category. This can be done via backend. Go to `Catalog > Manage Categories > [your category]` and then need to set `isAnchor` property to `Yes`.

Then make brands attribute to visible for layered navigation. This is also can be done via backend. Go to `Catalog > Manage Attributes > [your brand attribute]` and then change *visible in layered navigatio*n to yes.

You are done.

Comment: As Per ur guide i made a attribute and enebled in layred nevigation, the attribute shows in layred nevigation but velues of attribue not showing,

Comment: you need to set the frontend type of the attribute as `select` I guess.

Comment: ive done that also, http://www.uniquebattery.in/micromex.html see here